# What does this syntax mean (List<? extends Number> data)

Tags: java, generics, constructor

I'm trying to use the `charts4j` api and one of the constructors has this:

`public static Data newData(List<? extends Number> data)`

It looks like some form of generics to me, but I've never seen this notation before and I don't understand it.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/methods.html

Comment: @Down voter what did I do wrong?

Comment: I downvoted the question because it doesn't show research effort. I googled "java question mark extends" and immediately found prior SO questions as well as the Java Tutorials Generics article on wildcards.

Comment: @paulbellora I respect your down vote but please don't jump to conclusions.  No where did I say I didn't search, but that I didn't understand.

Comment: @code4me I believe you but the question doesn't *show* research effort. For the future, make sure to cite and link to resources that you've already read and explain why they haven't helped or what about them you didn't understand.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is an [upper-bounded wildcard](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/upperBounded.html): `? extends Number`.

It means that `data` can be a list of anything that is `Number` or a subclass, such as `List<Number>`, `List<Integer>`, `List<Double>`, etc.

Generics in Java are not covariant, so a `List<Double>` is not a `List<Number>`.  Here, a parameter of type `List<? extends Number>` allows `List<Double>` as well as `List<Number>`, but a parameter of type `List<Number>` does not allow `List<Double>`.

As for the `List` part, it could be anything that implements `List`, such as `LinkedList<Integer>` or `ArrayList<Double>`.

Comment: Thank you for the very clear and concise answer!

Comment: if you explain why to use `? extends Number` instead of `List<Number>` it would be great :)

Comment: @nachokk I added more about why `? extends Number` works better here.

Answer (score 1):

```
public static Data newData(List<? extends Number> data)
```

This defines a method that receives a collection implementing the `List` interface (`ArrayList`, for example), that contains any subclass of the `Number` class (even the `Number` class itself).

Indeed, this concept is related to generics and it's called an *Upper Bounded Wildcard*. Long story short: It allows you to write a method without a specific type restriction, but a hierarchy restriction instead.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is [wildcard](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/wildcards.html) in generics. It means the method will accept any List of type of class that extends Number.

Example: `List<Integer>, List<Double>`

Answer (score 1):

```
<T extends SomeClass>
```

is used when the actual parameter can be some class or any sub class of it. So in your case:

```
public static Data newData(List<? extends Number> data)
```

your method can accept a list of any class that is of type Number.

To learn more about Java generics refer:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/methods.html

Answer (score 0):

It is a generic type. It means that the `data` parameter is a List of any class that extends Number. i.e. If you have a custom class:

```
public class Nomber extends number {
    //stuff...
}
```

it will take a `List<Nomber>` as a variable.

Answer (score 0):

It means that the data list can only add a object of Number type or SubNumber type as Double, Integer...